Is there an analogy of associated points for sheaves on complex analytic spaces?
Let $\mathcal F$ be a coherent sheaf on a complex analytic space $X$.  I was wondering if there is an analogy to what is called associated points in scheme theory. Searching the internet didn't yield anything, and neither did browsing the indices of "Coherent Analytic Sheaves" by Grauert and Remmert, "Analytic Functions of Several Complex Variables" by Gunning and Rossi or "Complex Analytic Geometry" by Fischer. Does something like this exist, and what is a reference?
Here are my thoughts:
In scheme theory, associated points are rarely closed (e.g. the generic points of the support are associated), so I don't think it makes sense to think about points for complex analytic spaces. Maybe one can say that a reduced closed subspace $Y \subset X$ is associated to $\mathcal F$, if for any $y \in Y$ the ideal sheaf $I_{Y,y} \subset \mathcal O_{X,y}$ is the intersection of associated primes of $\mathcal F_x$ in $\mathcal O_{X,x}$? Note that even if $Y$ is irreducible (i.e. a nodal curve in $\mathbb C^2$), it's local defining ideal need not be a prime ideal (this happens at the node).
Here is my motivation: Given a short exact sequence of coherent sheaves
$$0 \to \mathcal F' \to \mathcal F \to \mathcal F'' \to 0 $$
on $X$ and an effective Cartier divisor $D \subset X$, I would like to argue that the restricted sequence
$$0  \to \mathcal F'|_D \to \mathcal F|_D \to \mathcal F''|_D \to 0$$
remains exact if $D$ does not contain any "associated points" of $\mathcal F''$.

Yes, there is a notion of associated prime ideals. See

Yum-tong Siu, Noether-Lasker decomposition of coherent analytic
subsheaves, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 135 (1969), 375-385;
doi:10.1090/S0002-9947-1969-0234019-8; MR 234019.

Theorem 4 implies that there is a locally finite of analytic subvarieties $\{Y_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $X$ such that for every $x \in X$, we have
$$\operatorname{Ass}_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}(\mathcal{F}_x) = \bigcup_{\{i \in I \vert x \in Y_i\}} \operatorname{Ass}_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}(\mathcal{O}_{Y_i,x}).$$
This version of Siu's theorem is stated as Theorem 2.10 in a recent paper of Fujino.
These $Y_i$ are called the associated subvarieties of $\mathcal{F}$.
